# MySQL Query - Select most recent configuration and most recent action

Tags: mysql, sql

I really need help solving this problem with a single query.

I have four tables:

```
[Assets]
[id | serial_number | date_created] (other stuff)

[Parts]
[id | unit_number | date_created] (other stuff)

[Groups]
[id | asset_id | part_id | date_created] (other stuff)

[Activity]
[id | group_id | date_recorded | action_id] (other stuff)
```

How can I select all the assets and find their most recent pairing (group) and within that group their latest activity. In one record row.

EDIT: What I Have tried:

1. I did it with `php` but it is extremely ugly and requires three separate queries.
2. I selected all the attributes from each table via a separate `SELECT`, which I assume is a horrible way of doing it

   ```
   SELECT
       *,
       (
           SELECT
               part_id
           FROM
               groups
           ORDER BY
               date_created 
           DESC
           LIMIT 1
       ) AS part_id
   FROM
       assets
   ```

To grab just the `part_id` I do a nested select, but if I need 9 attributes I need 9 nested selects which is a bad way?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I will edit my question with what I have tried, I apologize for looking like I am asking you to do my work but my question got cleared and I had to rewrite it. Give me a sec sir.

Comment: look into outer/cross apply maybe

Answer (score 0):

Your query suggests the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM assets a cross join
     (select *
      from groups
      order by date_created
      limit 1
     ) g
```

However, I suspect that you might really want to join assets and groups on some field (group id?  part id?) and choose the most recent record based on that field.  The following query does this, assuming parts is the matching field:

```
SELECT *
FROM assets a join
     (select *
      from groups g join
           (select g.part_id, max(date_created) as maxdate
            from groups g
            group by g.part-id
           ) gmax
           on g.part_id = gmax.part_id and
              g.date_created = gmax.maxdate
     ) g
     on a.parts_id = g.parts_id
```